# aura of the sinister (it's about Babylon)

Tags: traduction, adjectifs

This is a text about ancient Babylon. Nothing in context gives me real clue of "sinister" meaning here, used as a noun — except that it gives an analysis of necromancy in then ancient city. Should I understand "sinister" here as "omen" ?

> Such stories reflected not only the faint aura of the sinister that had always clung to Babylonian learning, but also an ambition on the part of Jewish scholars to lay claim to its inheritance.

Quelles sont les possibilités pour interpréter "sinister" ici ? …"une vague atmosphère de présage" ? Lié au fait que les Babyloniens pratiquaient la nécromancie. Car "sinistre" seul ici ne veut rien dire.

Regarding the meaning of the English sentence, see [the related question on English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126108/what-does-faint-aura-of-the-sinister-mean-in-this-context). Note that *sinister* in the English sentence should be understood as an adjective: “the faint aura of the sinister” means “the faint aura of something that is sinister”.

Comment: It seems you are asking us on French Language to understand the English sentence? That is not what French Language is about. **You** are supposed first to  **explain what sinister means in English in this sentence**, then we might be able to help you for the French.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's exactly what I did : I gave context and supposed meaning, which I question because it's doesnt make sense in french. This is what translation is about : if I struggle to understand in english, how can I translate in french ? If I had no problem to exactly understand it in english, I would not struggle to translate t, and would not bother to post here… :-) To sum it up, a "learning" cannot be "sinister", unless in the sense I surmised in my first post.

Comment: What text? Could you give more context? In what language was this text originally written?

Comment: Original text is in english of course. It's an essay about Babylon, as already stade in my #1.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see where in question you are explaining the English sentence. You are asking "Quelles sont les possibilités pour interpréter "sinister" ici ?" which is clearly asking for an explanation on the meaning of the word *sinister* in English.  You are on the wrong site for this.

Comment: Clearly you did not read what I wrote. I don't need to know the meaning of the word sinister. I need to understand how to translate it in french when used here in a very peculiar way in english.

Comment: I did read carefully. You write "a "learning" cannot be "sinister" ", if you want to discuss this I still repeat you are in the wrong place. We need to know what the word *sinister* means in this context.

Comment: We need to know it indeed. And to translate it in french. In that case, I will not translate it by "sinistre" without some more explanation.

Comment: What is the title of the essay then? Does it have an author?…

Comment: @Gilles, concerning your edit. Don't you think questions should be self contained and OP should have provided the explanation in the first place? Same with source, it's a quote from [that book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Shadow_of_the_Sword_(book)).

Comment: It seems to me that my first post gave plenty of explanation, context and aspects to the question…

Comment: In the future, please take care before posting your questions, instead of posting the same off-topic question twice. People have gone through considerable trouble to salvage your questions, in the future you can't always expect people to help you so much.

Comment: Why my initial question (my topic) should be "off-topic" ? I'm not sure to understand.

Comment: @kantx: Understanding English is not something this site was made for. Questions about difficult translations can be asked if you already cornered the meaning, but failed to find an appropriate way to express it in French.

Comment: @stephane : that was exactly my case, and precisely what I explained in my first post.

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas besoin de chercher midi à quatorze heures. L'adjectif *sinister* en anglais a à peu près le même sens que l'adjectif *sinistre* en français. Il n'y a pas particulièrement de connotation de présage ; *sinistre* peut qualifier un mauvais présage, mais il indique le caractère mauvais, pas le fait qu'il s'agisse d'un présage. La phrase citée ne fait aucune allusion à un quelconque présage. Je propose donc :

> De telles histoires reflétaient non seulement le caractère vaguement sinistre qui avait toujours été attaché au savoir Babylonien, …

ou

> De telles histoires reflétaient non seulement le caractère vaguement sinistre qui avait toujours entaché le savoir Babylonien, …

Comment: J'avais déjà songé à ces solutions, qui n'ont malheureusement pas de sens clair en français.

Comment: @kantx Et en ont-elles dans la phrase en anglais ? Il me semble que le problèmpe ici n'est pas une question de langue française mais de compréhension de texte, et comme le texte est en anglais la question n'est pas posée au bon endroit. À voir sur [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com) ou [History](http://history.stackexchange.com/). La réponse donnée est la seule qui puisse répondre à la question posée sur French Language.

Answer (score 0):

Gilles a donné la seule bonne réponse (+1) aussi je ne m'attarderai pas à en donner une autre, parce que d'une part elle est simple, et d'autre part elle est juste.

Cependant, il semble que l'OP ait du mal à saisir le sens du texte original. Ce n'est AMHA pas une question de langue, mais une question de référence culturelle. Il s'agit d'une référence biblique: la tour de Babel.

Je n'aurai pas la prétention d'expliquer la problématique: en effet cette explication est à la fois hermétique et extrêmement riche de sens, et le moins qu'on puisse dire, c'est qu'elle a fait couler beaucoup d'encre. Notons simplement que jamais un texte aussi court (11 lignes) n'a été autant expliqué (je ne saurait dire combien exactement, mais il me semble que le nombre de livres écrit à ce sujet est plus de l'ordre du millier).

Alors revenons-en à notre phrase, on parle de.. disons: la connaissance babylonienne si sinistrement auréolée. Ce qu'il faut retenir de la tour de Babel à ce sujet, c'est la vanité de l'homme à croire que la connaissance peut le rendre égal à Dieu, et le fait que Dieu ne le permet pas (destruction de la tour/ division de l'humanité en langues différentes).